# MySQL function IF gives error

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE 111_02DetermineCdeApproachable
SELECT view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id,
SELECT Last(group_id) FROM view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup AS group_id,
if(group_id = 60 or group_id = 52 or group_id = 49 or group_id = 40 or group_id = 30,2,1) AS cde_approachable FROM tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate
INNER JOIN view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup
ON (tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate.recipient_id = view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id)
AND (tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate.max_create_date = view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.create_date)
GROUP BY view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id;
```

Error in query!

> `CREATE TABLE 111_02DetermineCdeApproachable SELECT
>   view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id, SELECT Last(group_id)
>   FROM view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup AS group_id, if(group_id = 60 or
>   group_id = 52 or group_id = 49 or group_id = 40 or group_id = 30,2,1)
>   AS cde_approachable FROM tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate INNER JOIN
>   view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup ON
>   (tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate.recipient_id =
>   view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id) AND
>   (tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate.max_create_date =
>   view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.create_date) GROUP BY
>   view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id`
>
> You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near `'SELECT Last(group_id) FROM
>   view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup AS group_id, if(grou'` at line 3

Comment: There's a comma missing before `if` (since it's a column for itself), as you can see by your error. Also note that you used `groep_id` twice (instead of `group_id`, but this seems to just be a mis-paste as it's correct in the error).

Comment: if('group_id' = 60 or like that?

Comment: Errors nearly always occur immediately to the left of the first character idenitified in the error message.

Comment: @LeBro What you've done: `SELECT column_a column_b`. What you should do: `SELECT column_a, column_b`.

Comment: Maybe you can paste the whole script if it's not that long.

Comment: CREATE TABLE 111_02DetermineCdeApproachable
SELECT view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id,
Last(view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.group_id)
if(group_id = 60 or groep_id = 52 or group_id = 49 or group_id = 40 or groep_id = 30,2,1) AS cde_approachable FROM tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate
INNER JOIN view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup
ON (tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate.recipient_id = view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id)
AND (tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate.max_create_date = view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.create_date)
GROUP BY view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id;

Comment: @LeBro Once again, you're missing a comma after `Last(view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.group_id)` to separate it from `if`. You also still have used `groep_id` twice instead of `group_id`.

Comment: There you go. As what they've said. `Last(view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.group_id),
  if(group_id = 60 or group_id = 52 or group_id = 49 or group_id = 40 or group_id = 30,2,1) AS cde_approachable`

Comment: thank you alll.... but it still won't work

Comment: CREATE TABLE 111_02DetermineCdeApproachable
SELECT view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id,
Last(view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.group_id), 
if(group_id = 60 or group_id = 52 or group_id = 49 or group_id = 40 or group_id = 30,2,1) AS cde_approachable FROM tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate
INNER JOIN view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup
ON (tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate.recipient_id = view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id)
AND (tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate.max_create_date = view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.create_date)
GROUP BY view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup.recipient_id;

Comment: yeap... the same error

Comment: @LeBro: I voted to close this question, as your requirements are not clear and you are not explaining them.

Comment: ok ravinder. i know little of mysql. my ms access is much better

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:-

```
if(group_id in (60, 49, 40) or groep_id in (52, 30, 2, 1) AS cde_approachable
```

If group_id and groep_id is not your pasting mistake. But if they are same then you must try somthing like this:-

```
if(group_id in (60, 49, 40, 52, 30, 2, 1) AS cde_approachable
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
CREATE TABLE 111_02DetermineCdeApproachable 
  SELECT v.recipient_id
       , Last( v.group_id )
       , if( group_id in ( 60, 52, 49, 40, 30 ), 2, 1 ) AS cde_approachable
  FROM tbl_111_01SelectMaxCreateDate t
       INNER JOIN view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup v
               ON ( t.recipient_id    = v.recipient_id ) 
              AND ( t.max_create_date = v.create_date )
  GROUP BY v.recipient_id;
```

Comment: Was it a syntax failure or not a desired output?

Comment: @LeBro: It is good to let us know what the error is. Post it. Your are hiding info which is required to analyse.

Comment: Error in query!
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT Last(group_id) FROM view_0501_011_01RecipientEgroup AS group_id, if(grou' at line 3

Comment: When said *`near`*, it must be either `'at'` or `'before'` that point. What does the sql contain before `'select last ...'`? Post entire sql statement used. Better update your question with the latest query used.

Comment: Ok... why did you use `'select'` before `'last'`? It is not required. And let me hope `'last'` is UDF.

Comment: You better post a new question with 1. table and view structure and relation in between them, 2. sample data in both of them, 3. What the expected `select` result to go as a new table `111_02DetermineCdeApproachable`, 4. What and why use of `'last'`. Otherwise, people on SO won't understand on what you actually are looking for.